Reducing the gap between a line of text and an image
I'm trying to add the source of a chart below it, however the distance between the line of text and the content of the chart is too big, as the chart has a big white space on its bottom (below 'Year'), which is added to the normal line space. How can I reduce this gap?
Thanks!
I tried to reducing the space at the bottom of the chart, but it didn't work. I also changed the sources text font so it has less superior space, but it wasn't enough.
Example

Assuming that it is an image from your device, you can select it, then use the Crop tool on the ribbon, to the far right.

You'll then have black rectangles on each side of the image, that you can manipulate at will the cropping distance.

It's not an image, it's a chart

A couple alternatives would be, either to, put the text inside a text box (that way you can manipulate it in the position wherever you like it), or to change the position of the text it self by selecting it -> right click -> Font - > Advanced -> Position : By (then adjust the spacing of the text and the chart).
